# Django form input not showing on frontend/html

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I'm working with django forms to create a software for an ice cream company and I'm having trouble with my django forms to show up on the front end of my website. I was able to have customer information show up but the customer's order won't show and I am confused what's going on.

**orderentry.html**

```
             <!--Basic Customer Information--> 
            <form method = "post">
                {% csrf_token %}
                {{ form.as_p }}
                {{ newOrder}}
                <button type = "submit">Place your order!</button> 
            </form>
```

**views.py**

```
from django.http.response import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.http import HttpResponse
import orderentry
from orderentry.forms import customerForm, customerInformation

def getCustomerInfo(request):
    form = customerForm(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            orderentry.forms.customer_first_name = form.cleaned_data['customer_first_name']
            orderentry.forms.customer_last_name = form.cleaned_data['customer_last_name']
            orderentry.forms.shipping_address = form.cleaned_data['shipping_address']
            orderentry.forms.billing_address = form.cleaned_data['billing_address']
            return redirect('/orderentry')

    else:
        form=customerForm()
    
    return render(request, 'orderentry.html', {'form' : form})

def getCustomerOrder(request):
    newOrder = customerInformation(request.POST)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if newOrder.is_valid():
            newOrder.save()
            #orderentry.forms.order_Item_Flavor = newOrder.cleaned_data['order_Item_Flavor']
            orderentry.forms.half_Pint_Count = newOrder.cleaned_data['half_Pint_Count']
            orderentry.forms.one_Quart_Count = newOrder.cleaned_data['one_Quart_Count']
            orderentry.forms.pint_Count = newOrder.cleaned_data['pint_Count']
            orderentry.forms.half_Gallon_Count = newOrder.cleaned_data['half_Gallon_Count']
            orderentry.forms.gallon_Count = newOrder.cleaned_data['gallon_Count']
            orderentry.forms.cost = newOrder.cleaned_data['cost']
            return redirect('/orderentry')
        else:
            print("error")

    else:
        newOrder=customerInformation()
    
    return render(request, 'orderentry.html', {'newOrder' : newOrder})
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from orderentry.models import customerInfo, orderInfo

class customerForm(forms.ModelForm):

    customer_first_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    customer_last_name = forms.CharField(max_length=30)
    shipping_address = forms.CharField(max_length=60)
    billing_address = forms.CharField(max_length=60)

    class Meta:
        model = customerInfo
        fields = ('customer_first_name','customer_last_name','shipping_address', 'billing_address',)

class customerInformation(forms.ModelForm):
    #order_Item_Flavor = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=['vanilla','chocolate','strawberry','cookiesncream'])
    half_Pint_Count = forms.IntegerField()
    one_Quart_Count = forms.IntegerField()
    pint_Count = forms.IntegerField()
    half_Gallon_Count = forms.IntegerField()
    gallon_Count = forms.IntegerField()
    cost = forms.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        model = orderInfo
        fields = ('half_Pint_Count', 'one_Quart_Count', 'pint_Count', 'half_Gallon_Count', 'gallon_Count', 'cost',)
```

**models.py**

```
class customerInfo (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Customer Information"
        verbose_name_plural = "Customer Information"

    customer_first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    customer_last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    shipping_address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    billing_address = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    customer_status_choices = [('PREFERRED', 'preferred'), ('OKAY', 'okay'), ('SHAKY', 'shaky')]
    customer_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices = customer_status_choices, default="PREFERRED")

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s %s' % (self.customer_first_name, self.customer_last_name)

class orderInfo (models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Order Information"
        verbose_name_plural = "Order Information"
    
    order_Item_Flavor = models.ForeignKey('inventory.item', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    half_Pint_Count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    one_Quart_Count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    pint_Count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    half_Gallon_Count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    gallon_Count = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    cost = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(customerInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default = 0)

    def __str__(self):
        return '%s, Half Pint: %s, Quart: %s, Pint: %s, Half Gallon: %s, Gallon: %s, $%s' % (self.order_Item_Flavor, 
        self.half_Pint_Count, self.one_Quart_Count, self.pint_Count, self.half_Gallon_Count, self.gallon_Count, 
        self.cost)
```

**urls.py**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.getCustomerInfo, name = 'orderentry'),
    path('', views.getCustomerOrder, name = 'orderentry'),
```

Essentially, this is what it looks like and I am unsure how to get the customerInformation to be shown on the front end.
[Front End](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D8kcp.jpg)

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance, it is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please show your `urls.py`.

Comment: @bichanna just updated with it!

Comment: Did you solve your problem?

Comment: sorry! yes, the problem was fixed and thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think `getCustomerOrder` gets called properly, but it does not get called when you access your `orderentry.html` (I don't your url for this file). That means `newOrder` is not passed to the template (your `orderentry.html`).

So, you have to pass `newOrder` to your template in `getCustomerInfo`:

```
# inside getCustomerInfo func (I omitted other code)
else:
   newOrder=customerInformation() # you used 'newOrder', so I'm using the same name. You can change it, of course.
   form=customerForm()

return render(request, 'orderentry.html', {'form' : form, "newOrder": newOrder}) # notice! you have to put 'newOrder' in this dictionary (or context).
```

And as of now, your order info does not get saved when user clicks on 'Place your order!' button. So, you have to put the code that saves order after `if request.method == 'POST':` in `getCustomerOrder` into `getCustomerInfo`.

Comment: Just tried this and it looks like it's finally showing up. I was wondering if you can explain why I have to put newOrder=customerInformation() within the getCustomerInfo? Also, does that mean if I were to make more functions, would I have to again, include it inside of the getCustomerInfo function?

Comment: I also ran into a new problem where the data being inputted into getCustomerOrder isn't being saved into the database at all. Any guidance on that?

Comment: @JacobLe, you have to write the code that saves, then.